# Is it true that JOINS can be used everywhere to replace Subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I heard people saying that table joins can be used everywhere to replace sub-queries. I tested it in my query, but found that appropriate data set was only retrieved when I used sub-queries. I was not able to get same data set using joins. I am not sure if what I found is right because I am a newcomer in RDBMS, thus not so much experienced. I will try to draw the schema (in words) of the database in which I was experimenting:

The database has two tables:

`Users` (**ID**, Name, City) and Friendship (***ID***, ***Friend_ID***)

`Goal`: Users table is designed to store simple user data and Friendship table represents Friendship between users. Friendship table has both the columns as foreign keys, referencing to Users.ID. Tables have many-to-many relationship between them.

Question: I have to retrieve Users.ID and Users.Name of all the Users, which are not friends with a particular user x, but are from same city (much like fb's friend suggestion system).

By using subquery, I am able to achieve this. Query looks like:

```
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM USERS AS U
WHERE U.ID NOT IN (SELECT FRIENDS_ID
                   FROM FRIENDSHIP,
                        USERS
                   WHERE USERS.ID = FRIENDSHIP.ID AND USERS.ID = x)
  AND U.ID != x AND CITY LIKE '% A_CITY%';
```

Example entries:

```
Users
```

Id = 1 Name = Jon City = Mumbai

Id=2 Name=Doe  City=Mumbai

Id=3  Name=Arun  City=Mumbai

Id=4 Name=Prakash City=Delhi

```
Friendship
```

Id= 1 Friends_Id = 2

Id = 2 Friends_Id=1

Id = 2 Friends_Id = 3

Id = 3 Friends_Id = 2

Can I get the same data set in a single query by performing joins. How? Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks.

Note: I used inner join in the sub-query by specifying both tables: Friendship, Users. Omitting the Users table and using the U from outside, gives an error (But if not using alias for the table Users, query becomes syntactically okay but result from this query  includes ID's and names of users, who have more than one friends, including the user having ID x. Interesting, but is not the topic of the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `not in` you can use `left join` and check for `is null`:

```
select u.id, u.name 
from  Users u 
left join Friends f on u.id = f.id and f.friend_id = @person
where u.city like '%city%' and f.friend_id is null and u.id <> @person;
```

There are some cases where you can't work out your way with just inner/left/right joins, but your case is not one of them.

Please check sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c5b1/14

Also about your note: What you tried to do can be achieved with `lateral` join or `cross apply` depending on the engine you are using.

Comment: I'm pretty sure City isn't a parameter.

Comment: @Aheho it is irrelevant to the question, but you are right.

Comment: I'd be curious to see if SQL servers would optimize a subquery statement into effectively a join. As in does it really make a difference which way you do it?

Comment: @Josh In most cases it will, especially in newer versions of sqlserver/postgre/mysql. But some older versions of rdbms could've provide drastically different execution plans.

Comment: I think it won't help because the query will return rows with f.friend_id set to null only. A user can have other friends. For example a user having two friends x (the current user) and some one else having id y, will have 2 entries in the join and data related to this person woill be returned, where frienship.id = z and friendship.id = y. If I am missing something, please clear it by posting an answer.

Comment: But you never actually reference the city of @Person so I'm not sure how this could work.

Comment: @Aheho There is no reference of `@person` city in initial query as well.

Comment: @user5818995 can you rephrase that or put example data in your question?

Comment: @vittore, You are correct, I misread the original query, but it was mentioned as one of the requirements of the results. It's suppose to list all users within the same city, that are currently not friends with a given user.

Comment: @Aheho and I expect it to be known beforehand.

Comment: @user5818995 see link for sql pad

Comment: @vittore you are hard coding friendship.friend_id . Think of a case where I have to retrieve all the user data of users who belong to the same city but are not friends with user x.

Comment: @user5818995 that is exactly what query is doing `@person` is id of user x.

Comment: Note that NOT IN to LEFT JOIN conversion like this adds duplicate rows if duplicates are found in the Friends table.

Comment: "*table joins can be used everywhere to replace sub-queries*" that statement is plain wrong (because of the "everywhere"). In a one-to-many relationship a join and a sub-query will return very different results.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name there is lateral join for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your query using only joins. The trick is to join to the User tables once with an inner join to identify users within the same city and reference the Friendship table with a left join and a null check to identify non-friends.

```
SELECT
     U1.ID,
     U1.Name
FROM
    USERS U1
INNER JOIN
    USERS U2
ON
     U1.CITY = U2.CITY
LEFT JOIN
     FRIENDSHIP F
ON
    U2.ID = F.ID AND
    U1.ID = F.FRIEND_ID
WHERE
     U2.id = X AND
     U1.ID <> U2.id AND
     F.id IS NULL
```

The above query doesn't handle the situation where USER x's primary key is in the FRIEND_ID column of the FRIENDSHIP table. I assume because your subquery version doesn't handle that situation, perhaps you create 2 rows for each friendship, or friendships are not bi-directional.

Comment: good point on bi-directional friendship. I decided not to pursuit it since it wasn't in original query.

Comment: F.ID is null, I am thinking about this condition. What if a user has two or more friends including the user with ID x. Will it work?

Comment: Any friends of user X will be excluded because of the F.ID is null condition.

Comment: Are you familiar with LEFT JOINs? That's the key to this strategy.

Answer (score -2):

Joins and subqueries can be used to achieve similar results in some cases, but certainly not all.  As an example, this query with a subquery could not be achieve vis-a-vis a join:

```
SELECT ID, COLUMN1, COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE COLUMN2 NOT IN (VALUES1, VALUES2)
)
GROUP BY ID;
```

This is only one example, but there are many.

Conversely, you cannot get information from another table by using a subquery without joining it.

As to your example

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM USERS AS U 
WHERE U.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT FRIENDS_ID FROM FRIENDSHIP, USERS 
    WHERE USERS.ID = FRIENDSHIP.ID AND USERS.ID = x) 
AND U.ID != x AND CITY LIKE '% A_CITY%';
```

This could be constructed as:

```
select ID, NAME from users u
join FRIENDSHIP f        on f.ID = u.ID
where u.ID = x
and u.ID != y
and CITY like '%A_CITY';
```

I changed your second x to a y assumptively, so it wouldn't cause confusion.

Of course, you may also want to LEFT JOIN aka LEFT OUTER JOIN if there is a chance that there may be multiple results in the FRIENDSHIP table.

Comment: Your second query is just wrong, what will happen if person is friend with two people from that city?

Comment: There is no y, I have to use the same x in inner and outer query I think.

Comment: Also you first query does not need subquery and joins at all:  `SELECT ID, COLUMN1, COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE
WHERE  COLUMN2 NOT IN (VALUES1, VALUES2)
GROUP BY ID;`

Comment: vittore, you're missing the DISTINCT in that original query.  Since I'm running a count(*) I don't want to exclude rows to the total...I want to exclude that ID entirely.

Comment: You seem to have some misconception about how this query would work. Spin off DB and put some data in it and execute both yours and my queries.

Comment: Distinct in subquery would not matter  `where a not in (1,2,3)` works same way as `where a not in (1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)`. Also ID seems to be primary key on your table, is it not?

Comment: I think your presumption is that there's only one instance of each ID in the USERS table.  In my SELECT DISTINCT subquery example I'm assuming there's more than one instance of an ID.  I want to entirely exclude those IDs, not just the rows that don't have VALUES1 || VALUES2.